# Change Namespace of Childern Nodes SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

`<ret2:formFields xsi:type="ret1:FormFieldsType" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">`

I want to know how can I do the following? The namespace of children are getting changed by setting the `xsi:type` attribute.

**My Code:**

```
$ret2FormFields = $ret2FileBody->addChild('ret2:formFields', null, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
    $ret2FormFields->addAttribute("xsi:type", "ret1:FormFieldsType", 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');

        $ret2FormFields->addChild('ret1:isReverseReplace', false);
        $ret2FormFields->addChild('ret1:payDayDate', '2018-04-10'); /** @todo date will be dynamic */
```

**Expected XML:**

```
<ret2:formFields xsi:type="ret1:FormFieldsType" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ret1:isReverseReplace>false</ret1:isReverseReplace>
    <ret1:payDayDate>2018-04-10</ret1:payDayDate>
</ret2:formFields>
```

**My Incorrect XML:**

```
<ret2:formFields xmlns:ret2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ret2:type="ret1:FormFieldsType">
    <ret1:isReverseReplace>false</ret1:isReverseReplace>
    <ret1:payDayDate>2018-04-10</ret1:payDayDate>
</ret2:formFields>
```

I am stuck how to change the children namespaces `ret1` without changing the parent namespace `ret2`

Comment: If you [edit] your question to include a [mcve], I'll update my answer with tested code.

Comment: actually it is setting `type` attribute with `xis:type=ret1:FormFields` like (here) [https://github.com/InlandRevenue/Gateway_Services-Returns-and-Information/blob/master/Service%20-%20Payday%20Filing/Employment%20Information/sample%20messages/body-ei-returnfile-request.xml]

Comment: @IMSoP I have updated my question added the code. Can you please have a look at that now?

Comment: 124 lines of code is not a "minimal" example; nor have you included the actual and expected output of that full example, so it's not really "reproducible" either. Not only can you help others to help you by making your question easier to read, it will help you learn to break problems down, which is one of the most important skills in programming.

Comment: Actually, I have added the link which is the output I want to produce using SimpleXmlElment. Added 124 lines because the XML is a kind of tree on nodes inter linked. Thanks

Comment: Also, my problem starts on line number 42. This is the complete Output I want to generate.
https://github.com/InlandRevenue/Gateway_Services-Returns-and-Information/blob/master/Service%20-%20Payday%20Filing/Employment%20Information/sample%20messages/body-ei-returnfile-request.xml

Comment: Did you read the help page I linked to? It doesn't matter whether the _original_ example is one hundred or even ten thousand lines long; your job, to help both yourself and other people, is to create a _smaller_ example that still shows the problem. Delete chunks of code that you don't think are relevant to the problem; if the problem goes away, put them back - _and now you've learned something about the problem_. Repeat until either you figure out the problem yourself, or you have a better example to share with others.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong namespace to `addChild` here:

```
addChild('ret2:formFields', null, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
```

This tells SimpleXML that you want the element to have prefix `ret2` and namespace URI `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`, so it will generate:

```
<ret2:formFields xmlns:ret2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

You don't show in your example what the prefix `ret2` has been assigned elsewhere in the document, but that's what you need to provide, e.g.:

```
addChild('ret2:formFields', null, 'http://example.org/mynamespaces/ret2');
```